# GAE Python - Cron job doesn't execute on the target module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, cron, gae-module

I've just implemented modules on GAE and am trying to run a Cron job from a certain module. My app.yaml has following values at the top:

```
application: myapp
module: default
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
#all handlers
```

The reporting.yaml for the module I am trying to activate has the following settings:

```
application: myapp
module: reporting
version: 1
instance_class: B4
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
#same handlers as app.yaml
```

Finally my cron.yaml looks as following:

```
cron:
- description: update reports
  url: /update
  schedule: every day 12:00
  target: reporting
```

I need the module because the job requires more memory then the normal instance offers. For some reason however, when I look in the Logs of my app, it keeps executing the cron job on the default module. Why is it not accepting the target parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I missed to upload the module itself with following command:

```
appcfg update app.yaml reporting.yaml
```

After doing this, the target parameter worked.

Comment: Can you tell me how to properly set up the handlers for your cron job? I have a similar problem where I'm trying to load another module that needs more memory... just not sure how to setup the handlers in order to run a *.py script as a cron job. So, for example, I have abc.py that I want to run as a cron job that's part of module.yaml. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't use the distpatch.yaml, so I guess you don't have to update it. My handler in this case would be first line "- url: /update" and then second line "script: update.app" which would call the app from update.py

Comment: Thanks for the response -- could you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924934/cron-yaml-doesnt-route-requests-to-proper-module-on-dev-server) and see if you see something wrong? I feel I'm doing everything correctly, but I'm getting 404 errors when I'm trying to run a cron job..

Comment: Okay, fixed it -- I needed to specifically update cron.yaml with appcfg.py update_cron

Comment: Great. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below text from [GAE document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron?hl=ko#Python_app_yaml_Cron_and_app_versions) - target element for version not module.

> If the target parameter has been set for a job, the request is sent to
>   the specified **version**.

How about forward cron job to your target module as like the below example code in [GAE document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/?hl=ko#Python_Communication_between_modules)?

```
import urllib2
from google.appengine.api import modules

url = "http://%s/" % modules.get_hostname(module="reporting")
try:
  result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  doSomethingWithResult(result)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
  handleError(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Wonil. Turns out I just had to update the module properly.